# What is the best way to work with React Js: Redux, Hooks or Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, mern

I just recently started learning React and 3 different friends told me that the best way is with Redux, Hooks and context respectively
I'm building a MERN webapp with 3 differents roles, authentication and grhaphics, so what do you recommend ?

Comment: You don't need to learn Redux anymore, use Hooks and Functional Components is the best way

Comment: This is opinion based, so its not something we can really help answer. Look around for some blog posts or writeups and they'll give you better insight.

Comment: Check out this tutorial, https://scrimba.com/g/glearnreact, check out lesson 51 first, "Hooks Intro" , the lesson is a amendment to the course as React.js has really stopped embracing classes due to difficulties finding best optimizations which is not a problem with functional components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux and Hooks work very well together, as described in the [Redux official docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks). This is also [mentioned in the React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-do-hooks-mean-for-popular-apis-like-redux-connect-and-react-router) by the way.

**For simple state, hooks alone is more than enough. For more complex applications, relying only on hooks without Redux (or some kind of global state) is incredibly difficult.**

I would even go as far as to say that just hooks and context for a big application is also hard to maintain.

Here is a [small project](https://github.com/yuanworks/react-md-table-generator) I am doing using Redux's `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks. I just started it so it's good to see the boilerplate code that needed to be added.

**Personally, I feel that the new Redux hooks are much easier to work with than Redux without hooks.**